# how to use name variables in php?

Tags: php

Hello I was working on using passed values to the other php file. However every time I tried use the value of name variable conjunction with ordinary variable below, PHP won't read it !

```
global $counterforlist;
 $counterforlist= 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counterforlist = $counterforlist +1;
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber$counterforlist' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"   ; 
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany$counterforlist' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>" ;
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'dateforService$counterforlist' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"   ;
echo "<td><a href=\"update_request.php?jobrequestnumber{$counterforlist}={$row['jobrequestnumber']}&requestingcompany{$counterforlist}={$row['requestingcompany']}&dateforService{$counterforlist}={$row['dateforService']}&{$counterforlist}={$counterforlist}\">Update</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?jobrequestnumber=".$row['jobrequestnumber']."'>Delete</a></td>"; //too
echo "</tr>";
<?php include('update_request.php');?>
```

---

This is the other php file calling those values
in update_request....

```
<?php 
global $counterforlist;

$jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"."$counterforlist"];
$requestingcompany=$_GET["requestingcompany"."$counterforlist"];
$dateforService=$_GET["dateforService"."$counterforlist"]; 

$required_array=array($jobrequestnumber,$requestingcompany,$dateforService);
$errors = array();
$errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_array, $_POST));
if (empty($errors)){
// Database submission only proceeds if there were NO errors.
    $query =    "UPDATE jobrequest SET 
                        requestingcompany = '{$requestingcompany}',
                        dateforService = {$dateforService} 
                    WHERE jobrequestnumber ={$jobrequestnumber}";
                    echo $jobrequestnumber;
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

---

error messages

`Notice: Undefined index: jobrequestnumber in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 7`

`Notice: Undefined index: requestingcompany in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 8`

`Notice: Undefined index: dateforService in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\capstone\update_request.php on line 9`

---

If I were to declare variables again, It won't read values from previous php page.
Can you help me figure out what I have been missing :)

Comment: In your second file, do you declare `$counterforlist` anywhere?

Comment: Have you included the first file into the second ? (Like `include(<path_to_file1.php>)` or `require(<path_to_file1.php>)` or their `*_once(...)` counterparts.)

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.  You are also open to XSS attacks.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` when using arbitrary data in the context of HTML.

Comment: Undefined index: jobrequestnumber, it seems that you dont declare the counterfor list.

Comment: Yes I did Included all the file, and declared $counterforlist above the code, forgot to include that one in the content, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Brad, for now I am trying to figure out where I got wrong codes

Comment: Check spelling and lowercase/uppercase of characters in jobrequestnumber, etc. versus the spelling in the query and database.

Comment: You should use POST requests for updating the database as browsers may prefetch GET requests. You need to use javascript to submit hidden forms or for AJAX requests.

Comment: Yes I am using POST request, since the variable I was calling in the update_request is from the url variables, I used GET for those vars

Comment: Please, post your declaration

Comment: I think that cud be a way too ! thanks night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With file 1 you prepare a form containing fields like:

```
<input type='text' name='jobrequestnumberX'...
```

When the form is submitted the values of the form-fields are sent back and you can retrieve them from file 2 using $_GET["jobrequestnumberX"], but you need to know 'X'. 
This practice is kinf of "not right".

What you should do:

1. Remove `$counterforlist` from file 1 (all occurences). E.g. write:

   `echo "<td><a href=\"update_request.php?jobrequestnumber={$row['jobrequestnumber']}&requestingcompany={$row['requestingcompany']}&dateforService={$row['dateforService']}\">Update</a></td>";`
2. In file 2 retrieve the variables like this:

   `$jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"];`
   `$requestingcompany=$_GET["requestingcompany"];`
   `$dateforService=$_GET["dateforService"];`

Please, also, note Brad's comment about the highly insecure nature of your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to distinguish consecutive variable

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achive. Why to have variables with different names ? I really think the snippet above would achieve what you want. Have you tried it ? Try it (if not already) and let us know where/how it failed to do what you want, so we can fix it :)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use multiple variable saved in one name variable or more. This is why I used while loop, when I try to use it in the 2nd file, it failed to read them correctly, because of failure to call different variable names or other. So I used $counterforlist to use a specific row's information in the other file and update database.

Comment: But each link the user click's holds info about one row of data only. So each request processed in file 2 corresponds to one entity stored in the DB. If you need to pass values for multiple entities request (which I don't see the point why), you could use a different structure in file 1.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I just want to transfer information of 1 row, but I don't know how to select just one row from many. Ex) I selected one row from auto generated rows of information, and if I were to pass one row values, I need somehow one counter value or value to distinguish from value to value. job1, job2, job3, etc,

Comment: in page 2) $_GET['job'.$counter]; to dynamically call url values passed.

Comment: Like I said, you don't need the $counter. Each row is identified by the **value** of the variable $jobrequestnumber, **not** by the name of the variable. So, the row corresponding to `<job_no1>` will be modified through a link with `...?jobrequestnumber=<job_no1>`. Then on the server side you read tha **value** of the parameter **jobrequestnumber**, using `$_GET["jobrequestnumber"]` (which in this example will return `<job_no1>` - that's how you know which row in the DB-table to update).

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I am getting this errors : There were 3 errors in the form.

Comment: if (empty($errors)){
  $jobrequestnumber = $_GET['jobrequestnumber'];
    $requestingcompany = $_GET['requestingcompany'];
 $dateforService = $_GET['dateforService'];
 $counter = $_POST['jobrequestnumber'];
$jobrequestnumber = $_POST['jobrequestnumber'];
$requestingcompany = $_POST['requestingcompany'];
$dateforService = $_POST['dateforService'];

Comment: $query ="UPDATE jobrequest SET 
requestingcompany = '{$requestingcompany}',dateforService = {$dateforService} 
WHERE jobrequestnumber ={$jobrequestnumber}";
echo $jobrequestnumber;
$result = mysql_query($query);
// test to see if the update occurred
if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 1) {
// Success!
$message = "The page was successfully updated.";
} else {
$message = "The page could not be updated.";
$message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
}
echo $message;
}

Comment: else {
if (count($errors) == 1) {
$message = "There was 1 error in the form.";
}else{
$message = "There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
}
echo $message;
}

Comment: Where did that $_POST come into play ? I don't think there should be any POST-data (only GET). In any case I need to see both the HTML and the PHP in order to know what could be wrong. One thing is for sure: Getting rid of that `$counter` variable is one step towards the right direction :P

Comment: Oh I am sorry there are double dashes front of POST values, counter too :)

Comment: may I send you my file ?

Comment: Upload it somewhere and I will take a look.

Comment: Opps I forgot to change one function's content to GET too ! Thank you expert system very much.

Comment: So, is it working now ? I guess it does. Now that we got it working let me tell you associating operations that change data (like updating or deleting a row in the DB) with `GET` requests is a reaaally bad idea. Google about when to use GET and when POST.

Comment: Yes it does work fine. Thank you I will search for the requests. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't declare the counterfor

Why dont you do a

```
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'jobrequestnumber[]' value =".$row['jobrequestnumber']."></td>"   ; // results in the same jobrequestnumbers
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'requestingcompany[]' value =".$row['requestingcompany']."></td>" ;//this too
echo "<td><input type= 'text' name = 'dateforService[]' value =".$row['dateforService']."></td>"   ;
```

Then in your PHP
$Size = count($_GET["jobrequestnumber"]);

```
for($X=0; $Size<$X; $X++){
   $jobrequestnumber=$_GET["jobrequestnumber"][$X];
   $requestingcompany=$_GET["requestingcompany"][$X];
   $dateforService=$_GET["dateforService"][$X];

   // here update database
}
```

Now you don't need the counter variable.

or you can do

```
foreach ($_GET["jobrequestnumber"] as $key => $value){
   $jobrequestnumber=$value;
   $requestingcompany=$_GET["requestingcompany"][$key];
   $dateforService=$_GET["dateforService"][$key];

   // here update database
}
```